# Navigate To Home Conflict In React Router and Module Federation

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom, webpack-module-federation

I am trying to use React Router in a microfrontend setup as below;

I use React, React-Dom and React-Router-Dom as **shared** between federated applications.

```
    // package.json
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-router-dom": "6.9.0"
      }
```

And I have a container app which consumes remote applications with route setup;

```
 // App.tsx from Container Application
 const ChildPage = React.lazy(() => import('ChildApp/App')); // Where I import a remote application
    
    const mainAppRouter = createBrowserRouter([
      {
        path: '/',
        children: [
          {
            index: true,
            element: <HomePage />
          },
          {
            path: 'child/*',
            element: <ChildPage />
          },      
        ]
      }
    ]);

const App: React.FC = () => <RouterProvider router={mainAppRouter} />;
```

And I have child route configuration in the child application. Here its configuration;

```
     export const routes = [
      {
        path: '/',
        element: <HomePage />
      }, 
      {
        path: 'demo',
        element: <DemoPage />
      }
    ];
        
   const App: React.FC = () => {
   const appRoutes = useRoutes(routes);
        
   return appRoutes;
   };
```

This routing is working perfectly fine. I am able to navigate between container and child without any problem. My conflict starts when I want to return back to "home" page. Consider simple method in **Child App**;

```
 const navigate = useNavigate();
 navigate('/');
```

When this child app is working standalone ( without attaching to the container app ), navigate method simply redirect to index page of the application. However, when ChildApp is injected inside the Container App, **navigate('/')** method redirects to **index page of Container App**. I would like to keep the same behavior when ChildApp works standalone, so that it should redirect to its own index page.

I can not simply use **navigate('/child')**, because ChildApp should not need to know how container setups it route. I think that is not convenient for a complex architecture.

Is there any solution or practice or at least a "hack" to resolve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can navigate [relative](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link#relative) to a specific path, but I think this would result in a similar "coupling" like you describe. Perhaps you can pass this relative "path" in as a parameter to the federated component module? The link I shared is in the `Link` component's docs that explain this feature, but the [`useNavigate`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate) hook has the same capability.

Comment: Like If "basePath" is passed to federated component use that one, if not use '/' which means application is working standalone?  Then maybe I can implement a custom hook to navigate home which will navigate to this provided basePath or to default which is  '/' .

Yes all capabilities that <Link> element has is also available in useNavigate hook, I will try that 'relative'. Thank you

Comment: Yes, you understood me. If that works, or you find a solution you should certainly provide an answer.

Comment: Definitely will do, unless someone else has already tried such solutions successfully and shares before me, thank you :)

Comment: navigate('..', { relative: 'route' }); does the trick, although I could not clearly understand why. Document points "so .. will go up one Route level." .  When we go one route level down, it means it just goes by one single level where routes are defined , not to the root of whole application.  I think it acts like a tree, we just jump up to one single node, we do not jump in the root of the whole route tree. I am confused a little bit :)

Comment: I noticed that if you use `<Link to="">Container Index</Link>` in the container, it will take you to the index page of the container app. You can do the same thing with `navigate("")`.